# Passing two arguments to a range

Tags: vba, excel

I have two arguments that are integer (xxddd and dimen) and want to pass them to cells as you can see in the below code but it doesn't work.

```
Sub freind (xxddd, dimen)                        

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
Dim rngA As Range


Set rngA = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(xxddd, dimen).Address)
end sub
```

Comment: what if you fully qualify the range `Set rngA = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1).Address, ws.Cells(xxddd, dimen).Address)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub freind (xxddd, dimen)                        

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
    Dim rngA As Range

    Set rngA = ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(xxddd, dimen)
end sub
```

**EDIT:** re-reading your question I'm not sure why your original approach failed. Typically we try not to use `Cells()` without specifying a worksheet such as `ws.Cells()`, but in this case tagging `.Address` on the end of each argument should have resolved that...